# How to resolve org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException

Tags: java, spring

We migrated the local server application to the cloud environment.

The above exception is raising only in the cloud environment but we are not getting this exception in the local server.
In the cloud environment, we are getting some requests good responses and some requests are failing at uncategorized SQLException.

We are calling findByNamedQuery and namedParam using getHibernateTemplate().

It is getting an issue at this point.

In the local server we have not got any issues.

Local WebLogic server version:12.1.1.3
Cloud WebLogic server Version:12.2.1.4

And OS in local server lower version.
OS in cloud environment higher version using.

please find the stack trace :

org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not execute query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select pricingreq0_.CUST_ACCT_NBR as CUST1_14_, pricingreq0_.PRICING_DATE as PRICING2_14_, pricingreq0_.PROCESS_ID as PROCESS3_14_, pricingreq0_.REQUEST_SERVICE as REQUEST4_14_, pricingreq0_.SHPR_NBR as SHPR5_14_, pricingreq0_.C100_TS as C6_14_, pricingreq0_.C20_TS as C7_14_, pricingreq0_.C40_TS as C8_14_, pricingreq0_.CREATED_BY_NM as CREATED9_14_, pricingreq0_.CREATED_DT as CREATED10_14_, pricingreq0_.EFF_END_DT as EFF11_14_, pricingreq0_.EFF_START_DT as EFF12_14_, pricingreq0_.GENI as GENI14_, pricingreq0_.J20_TS as J14_14_, pricingreq0_.J30_TS as J15_14_, pricingreq0_.J40_TS as J16_14_, pricingreq0_.JVM_ID as JVM17_14_, pricingreq0_.NOI_PRICE_CHANGE as NOI18_14_, pricingreq0_.NOI_REVERSAL as NOI19_14_, pricingreq0_.NOI_TRANSITION as NOI20_14_, pricingreq0_.PRA_STATUS as PRA21_14_, pricingreq0_.REQUEST_TS as REQUEST22_14_, pricingreq0_.SERVER_NAME as SERVER23_14_, pricingreq0_.UPDATED_BY_NM as UPDATED24_14_, pricingreq0_.UPDATED_DT as UPDATED25_14_ from PT4RTRLIB.PRICING_REQUESTS_AUDIT pricingreq0_ where pricingreq0_.PRA_STATUS='20C' and pricingreq0_.CUST_ACCT_NBR=? and pricingreq0_.SHPR_NBR=? and pricingreq0_.PRICING_DATE=? and pricingreq0_.REQUEST_SERVICE=? and pricingreq0_.PROCESS_ID=?]; SQL state [HY001]; error code [-402]; [PWS0001] Function did not complete successfully.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [PWS0001] Function did not complete successfully
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(HibernateTemplate.java:1006)
at com.fedex.rerate.core.dao.impl.PRAHibernateDaoImpl.getPraList(PRAHibernateDaoImpl.java:42)
at com.fedex.rerate.core.ground.service.impl.FxgFhdRatingServiceImpl.processPricingDiscounts(FxgFhdRatingServiceImpl.java:438)
at com.fedex.rerate.ws.endpoint.FxgFhdRatingEndpoint.processRequest(FxgFhdRatingEndpoint.java:210)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

here is the code:

list = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(StringName, new String[] {"custAcctNbr","shprNbr","pricingDate", "requestService","processId"},
new Object[] {custAcctNbr, shprNbr, pricingDate, requestService,bds.toString() });

We are not able to identify the root cause of the issue.

Anyone suggestions could be appreciated

Comment: Can you share the stack trace from cloud. Probably that can help to recoganize the root cause.

Comment: yes i shared Jaswinder Singh